# Percentage padding difference only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, padding, percentage

I developed different responsive boxes for the news in the website I'm working in. And everything seems to be working fine except for the news inside the slider on the top of the main content. It displays properly in Chrome, Opera and even in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox. The problem seems to be in the `article` elements, specifically in the following lines of CSS code:

```
.home .first-level-post {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 45.1613%;
}
```

It's supposed to have a `height` of `280px`, that's why I chose `45.1613%` as its value. The container's `width` is of 620px, and it's 45.1613% is 280px.

When I switch the `padding-top` property off, it takes the `93.3333%` value which belongs to the `article` elements present outside the slider (which are 300px wide), displaying as it should, but that value does not work in the other browsers.

I've been dealing with this for a while I can't seem to find a solution.
You can properly check this issue [right here](http://www.radiofueguina.com/).

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is interpreting your padding based on a height of 0 due to inheriting from your .home article class.

Changing your CSS to this seemed to fix the issue for me in Firefox and not have an adverse effect in Chrome:

```
.home .first-level-post {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 45.1613%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh, my goodness! I can't believe it was that simple. I tried so many different things and forgot to try with height on this particular element.

Thank you so much, mate! I truly appreciate your help :)